# Failed to install LanguageTool on my Texstudio

Tags: texstudio, java

This this the message when I check my LanguageTool:

"where java: D:\JDK\bin\javaw.exe

JAVA: javaw.exe
java version "21.0.2" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 21.0.2+13-LTS-58, mixed mode, sharing)

Real-time checking is disabled!!!
Grammar checking is enabled.

Tries to start automatically.

LT current status: error

LT-URL: http://localhost:8081/v2/check"

I don't know why. Does anyone know how to tackle this issue?

The specific installation information is shown below:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.